# Flutter: PlatformException using EventChannel

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to implement `EventChannel` in my flutter app by am receiving the following error:

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SERVICES LIBRARY
>   ╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> The following PlatformException was thrown while activating platform
>   stream on channel  com.checkin.beacon.entered.beacons:
>
> PlatformException(error, Parameter specified as non-null is null:
>   method  kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull,
>   parameter args, null)

Here is my code:

Flutter side:

```
static const _enteredBeaconsEvent = const EventChannel("com.checkin.beacon.entered.beacons");

static void initialize () {
    _enteredBeaconsEvent.receiveBroadcastStream().listen((data) {
      print("data= $data");
    });
}
```

On Android Native (Kotlin), code is:

```
override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)

        EventChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "com.checkin.beacon.entered.beacons").setStreamHandler(object : EventChannel.StreamHandler {
            override fun onListen(args: Any, events: EventSink) {
                Log.d(TAG, "adding listener")

                events.success(true)
            }

            override fun onCancel(args: Any) {
                Log.d(TAG, "cancelling listener")
            }
        })
    }
```

I have searched alot but am unable to locate the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default all variables and parameters in Kotlin are non-null. If you want to pass a null parameter to the method you should add `?` to its type, for example:

```
override fun onListen(args: Any?, events: EventSink?) {...}
```

So, your final code will look like:

```kotlin
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)

        EventChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "com.checkin.beacon.entered.beacons").setStreamHandler(object : EventChannel.StreamHandler {
            override fun onListen(args: Any?, events: EventSink?) {
                Log.d(TAG, "adding listener")

                events.success(true)
            }

            override fun onCancel(args: Any?) {
                Log.d(TAG, "cancelling listener")
            }
        })
    }
```